# Grep to find lines starting at pattern A until pattern B is matched

Tags: log-files, grep, filtering, awk

I have a log that contains bits like this:

```
[2012-04-16 15:16:43,827: DEBUG/PoolWorker-2] {'feed': {}, 'bozo': 1, 'bozo_exception': URLError(error(110, 'Connection timed out'),), 'entries': []}
[2012-04-16 15:16:43,827: ERROR/PoolWorker-2] get_entries
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/myapp/app.py", line 491, in get_entries
    logging.getLogger(__name__).debug("Title: %s" % doc.title)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/feedparser.py", line 423, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError, "object has no attribute '%s'" % key
AttributeError: object has no attribute 'title'
[2012-04-16 15:16:43,828: INFO/MainProcess] Task myapp.do_task[4fe968ff-e069-4cfe-9a81-aece0d97c289] succeeded in 21.0481028557s: None
```

I would like to extract from it sections as follows:

1. When a line contains "ERROR" or "WARN" start filtering (and include this line)
2. When the next line starting with "[" is found, stop filtering (and don't include this line).

I'm pretty sure this is too much for Grep, so how to do it?

(Ok, instead of being lazy, I've figured it out - will post my solution.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me - not exactly as described above, but close enough:

```
awk '/ERROR|WARN/,/DEBUG|INFO/ { if ($0 !~ /(DEBUG|INFO)/) { print } }' < logfile
```

Very convenient that awk supports this: `/startpattern/,/stoppattern/ { }`. Unfortunately if the stop pattern is matched on the same line as the start pattern, it prints out that line only, hence the need for a different stop pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
cat importantstuff.log | grep 'File .*, line .*, in .*' -B 1 -A 2
```

Doesn't exactly answer the question, but I think it accomplishes the task.

The `-A` and `-B` flags for grep control lines of context after or before your match.

This works because grep groups adjacent matches, so you end up with nicely separated tracebacks:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sfquest.py", line 9, in b
    c()
  File "sfquest.py", line 15, in c
    d()
  File "sfquest.py", line 20, in d
    raise Exception('important information')
Exception: important information
--
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sfquest.py", line 9, in b
    c()
  File "sfquest.py", line 15, in c
    d()
  File "sfquest.py", line 20, in d
    raise Exception('important information')
Exception: important information
--
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sfquest.py", line 9, in b
    c()
  File "sfquest.py", line 15, in c
    d()
  File "sfquest.py", line 20, in d
    raise Exception('important information')
Exception: important information
```

Here's the example code I used to generate the traceback example:

```
import traceback                                                                

def a():                                                                        
    b()                                                                         

def b():                                                                        
    for i in range(10):                                                         
        try:                                                                    
            c()                                                                 
        except Exception, e:                                                    
            print 'bad stuff'                                                   
            print traceback.format_exc(e)                                       

def c():                                                                        
    d()                                                                         

def d():                                                                        
    for i in range(10):                                                         
        print 'random junk'                                                     
    raise Exception('important information')                                    

a()
```